# Scraping a Dynamic Page in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape [this website](http://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/index) in python. When we enter the company code (example 6177) the URL doesn't change but the page and the values on it, change.

There's just one cell that needs scraping. Screenshot attached for the exact cell. The cell's address is:

```
xpath - //*[@id="company"]/table[3]/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]
cssselector - #company > table:nth-child(17) > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(1)
```

How should I go on about this?

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Text `190,843` from a table induce `WebDriverWait`() and `visibility_of_element_located`() and use the following `xpath`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://mops.twse.com.tw/mops/web/index")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"keyword"))).send_keys("6177",Keys.ENTER)
print(WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='營收資訊']/following::table[1]//tr[4]/td[1]"))).text)
```

**Output**:

```
190,843
```